# How to use RegEx to ignore the first period and match all subsequent periods?

Tags: javascript, regex, number-formatting

How to use RegEx to ignore the first period and match all subsequent periods?

For example:

- 1.23 (no match)
- 1.23.45 (matches the second period)
- 1.23.45.56 (matches the second and third periods)

I am trying to limit users from entering invalid numbers. So I will be using this RegEx to replace matches with empty strings.

I currently have `/[^.0-9]+/` but it is not enough to disallow `.` after an (optional) initial `.`

Comment: Which flavor of regex/language are you using? Add it as a tag.

Comment: Don't you need to escape the `.` in `/[^.0-9]+/`, so it should be `/[^\.0-9]+/`?

Comment: `.replace(/^(\d+\.)([\d.]*)$/, function($0,$1,$2) { return $1+$2.replace(/\./g, ''); })`. Maybe the first dot should be made optional with `?`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! This addresses the question and gets the behavior that I was looking for! What would be the effect right now without making the first period optional?

Comment: Ok, I will post an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a regex that will match 1+ digits, a period, and then any number of digits and periods capturing these 2 parts into separate groups. Then, inside a replace callback method, remove all periods with an additional `replace`:

```js
var ss = ['1.23', '1.23.45', '1.23.45.56'];
var rx  = /^(\d+\.)([\d.]*)$/;
for (var s of ss) {
  var res = s.replace(rx, function($0,$1,$2) { 
     return $1+$2.replace(/\./g, ''); 
  });
  console.log(s, "=>", res);
}
```

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d+\.)` - Group 1 matching 1+ digits and a literal `.`
- `([\d.]*)` - zero or more chars other than digits and a literal dot
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I needed!

Comment: I realized that this pattern won't catch extra '.' if the number has a leading '.'

For example:
.9422....123 would be allowed

Comment: @Itsai: So, the issue is that a number may start with `.`? Just replace the first `+` with `*` to match 0 or more occurrences: `var rx  = /^(\d*\.)([\d.]*)$/;`. Does it fix the issue?

Comment: (just got a chance to try it.) Replacing the first `+` to `*` didn't fix the issue. And you are correct, a number in my example can start with `.`

The current pattern is allowing multiple `.` to be entered as long as we lead with a `.`

Comment: @Itsai: If you need to get `.9422123` out of `.9422....123`, the suggestion above [should work](https://jsfiddle.net/oxas7nb4/1/).

Comment: Thank you! It did work, I'm embarrassed to say what happened on my end. You're awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Constrain the number between the start `^` and end anchor `$`, then specify the number pattern you require. Such as:

`/^\d+\.?\d+?$/`

Which allows 1 or more numbers, followed by an optional period, then optional numbers.

Comment: This works to match numbers that I want to ultimately end up with. But I want to be able to match non-digits and non-first period(s) so that I can replace them with empty strings